# How to read data from excel for Maven project for Appium?

Tags: java, windows, maven, appium

I'm trying to write a code to automate a website testing for mobile using Appium. I need to read data from Excel. I'm writing the project as a Maven code. What all are to be taken from the maven repository?

NB:I'm a newbie to Java and any type of automation.

Answer (score 0):

You should use jxl or poi jar file to read data from excel,it also provide maven dependencies

Answer (score 0):

You can use poi.

Add the dependency in pom.xml

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
        <version>3.13</version>
</dependency>
```

Add a utility class in your project like below: make sure you get the sheet name(Sheet1 in class) correct

```
package com.appium.utils;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFCell;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFRow;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;
import org.apache.poi.util.POILogger;
import org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.PackageRelationshipCollection;
public class ExcelDriven {
public static XSSFWorkbook wb; 
public static XSSFSheet sheet;
public static XSSFRow row;
public static XSSFCell cell;
public static FileInputStream fis;

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
//   fis = new FileInputStream("/Users/tabish/Downloads/data.xlsx");    

}
public static String getCellData(int rownum,int col, String fileName)
{
     try {
         fis = new FileInputStream("/path/to/file/"+fileName+".xlsx");
         wb = new XSSFWorkbook(fis);
         sheet= wb.getSheet("Sheet1");
         row = sheet.getRow(rownum);
         cell = row.getCell(col);
    //   System.out.println(cell.getStringCellValue());
         if (cell==null){
             return "";
         }
         return cell.getStringCellValue();

    } 
     catch (Exception e)
     {
        System.out.println("In the Catch Block:"+e);
         return "Exception Occured";
    }

}
```

}

**Accesing Data**

```
while (!ExcelDriven.getCellData(0,i,"fileName").equals(""))
    {

        SomeClass.SomeMethod(ExcelDriven.getCellData(0,i,"fileName"));
        i++;
    }
```